# Devanagari characters do not render properly in gvim

Tags: vim, gvim, unicode

Devnagari characters do not render properly in gvim. They appear just as they do when typed in vim running in a terminal (consonants and vowels separated.)

Is there any way we can make vim handle devnagari characters properly?

Comment: Can you explain how to setup the system to input the Devnagari characters? I opened gvim, copied the Devnagari characters I found on [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) and did not notice any apparent problems.

Comment: While entering text, I use appropriate keyboard layout.

By the way, I, too tried copying devanagari text from wikipedia. Some characters appear OK. Most (more complex ones) don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** I searched a bit and found that you can use any monospaced font in vim but if you choose a non-monospaced font, the results will be ugly because vim has a fixed character cell. So, you can't use Devanagari fonts in gvim.

---

It seems to me that gVim treats every font as monospaced and that is creating the problem.

You can try other editors which can render the font correctly. Some of them are:

- **Gedit**

[image]

- **Emacs**

[image]

- **LibreOffice Writer** - *A word processor*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Upvoted for the same. But, I was looking forward to continue working in vim.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editor, you may try to change your terminal.
I use Konsole. It renders Devanagari properly.
https://konsole.kde.org/